# Why doesn't the decoder of MediaCodec output a unified YUV format(like YUV420P)?

Tags: android, yuv, android-mediacodec

"The MediaCodec decoders may produce data in ByteBuffers using one of the above formats or in a proprietary format. For example, devices based on Qualcomm SoCs commonly use OMX_QCOM_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar32m (#2141391876 / 0x7FA30C04)."

This make it difficult even not possible to deal with the output buffer.Why not use a unified YUV format?And why there are so many YUV color formats?

@fadden,I find it possible to decode to Surface and get the RGB buffer(like http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest.java.txt), Can I transfer the RGB buffer to YUV format and then encode it?

And,fadden,I tried to use API 18+ and came across some problems.I refered to the ContinuousCaptureActivity and ExtractMpegFramesTest code.
In ContinuousCaptureActivity:

```
    mEglCore = new EglCore(null, EglCore.FLAG_RECORDABLE);
    mDisplaySurface = new WindowSurface(mEglCore, holder.getSurface(), false);
    mDisplaySurface.makeCurrent();

    mFullFrameBlit = new FullFrameRect(
            new Texture2dProgram(Texture2dProgram.ProgramType.TEXTURE_EXT));
    mTextureId = mFullFrameBlit.createTextureObject();
    mCameraTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureId);
    mCameraTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mCameraTexture);
```

The FullFrameRect creates a SurfaceTexture and it is set to the camera preview texture.

But in ExtractMpegFramesTest, a CodecOutputSurface is used and it also creates a texture.How can I use the CodecOutputSurface and FullFrameRect together?(one supplies surface to receive the decoder output and one rescale and render to the encoder input surface.)

Comment: I can't answer the "why".  You can extract the RGB pixels from the output surface using `glReadPixels()`, convert the buffer to the appropriate YUV format (google for RGB to YUV conversion), and then encode from those.  http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest shows how to detect the supported input YUV format, but it uses generated frames rather than decoded frames to feed the encoder.  API 18+ recommended.

Comment: Thanks,fadden.You mean I should convert RGB buffer to the appropriate YUV format the device supports?And does each device surely support a common YUV format?If not,it is still very hard to deal with(conversion RGB to YUV).

Comment: Hi fadden,I updated the question I came across when I tried API 18+,please give me some help.

Comment: CodecOutputSurface is a helper class in the CTS test suite, FullFrameRect is a class in Grafika.  There is some overlap in features, but they are components of different approaches to the problem, and are not meant to be used together.  The code in CTS tests is designed for "headless" execution in a limited environment, so the Grafika code is probably better suited to an app.  Neither project has a fully-formed video transcoder, so they really just provide examples of how the different pieces are used.  It's up to you to fit them all together.

Comment: Can CodecOutputSurface rescale the decoder output size to encoder input size if I want to rescale the video?And does each device surely support a common YUV format like YUV420P?If not,it is still very hard to deal with(conversion RGB to YUV).

Comment: CodecOutputSurface holds the decoder output. The frame's dimensions are determined by the video input. To resize the video, you'd render the texture to a MediaCodec input surface with different dimensions. MediaCodec encoding from ByteBuffers will support one of a limited set of YUV formats, but decoding to ByteBuffers is not restricted (see http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q5).

Comment: Hi fadden,I tried to use CodecOutputSurface to get the decoder output RGBA buffer and then convert it to YUV buffer(in my case it is YUV420P and it is supported by the device).Then I feed the YUV buffer to MediaCodec encoder(color format is set to YUV420P).I really got the H264 file but it can't be played(and before a good h264 file can be played well on my device,also a mistranscoded h264 file can be played displaying the wrong image). Is my approach right in theory?

Comment: And what is the image size of the RGBA buffer CodecOutputSurface extracts?I find the width and height passed to the constructor can be set to the size of the target video,then I don't need to rescale the RGBA buffer when I convert it to YUV buffer.Is that right?Very thank you!

Comment: @fadden,help!As above described,I feed the encoder input buffer and get the output buffer then write it to h264 file.But the h264 file I got can't be recognized by player or the My MP4Box software(a software to mux video and audio track to mp4 file on pc).Is that some header info is missing?

Comment: The CodecOutputSurface width/height determine the size of the pbuffer, which holds the rendered output that glReadPixels() extracts.  So yes, that should be set to the desired size of the output frame, so that the image is scaled by GLES.  I don't know why the H.264 output isn't being accepted.

Comment: Thanks,fadden.I have found where the problem lays.Because I ignored the BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG frame buffer and didn't write it to the file.Then I wrote it to the h264 file and it's playable.But I am still not very clear how it works.Any way,this solved my problem.Then I will try to mux the h264 and aac track to mp4 file.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to answer the *'why'* part. With your kind permission, I will change the order of the questions.

> And why there are so many YUV color formats?

[YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) is only one of many color spaces used to represent visual information. For many technical and historical reasons, this color space is most popular for photographical data (including video). Wikipedia claims that YUV was invented when television began to transform from BW to color. Back then, these were analogue signals. Later, different engineers in different corporations and countries began to independently invent the ways to store this YUV data in digital format. No wonder that they did not come up with one format.

Furthermore, the YUV formats differ in the volume of chroma information they store. It's quite natural that YUV 420, 422, and 444 all have right to exist, giving different compromises between precision and size.

Finally, some of the differences in YUV formats are related to physical layout of the pixels, and are optimized for different optical sensors.

Which brings us to the first part of your question:

> Why not use a unified YUV format?

Transfer of photo information from the optical sensor to computer (smartphone) memory is a technical challenge. When we speak about a many-megapixel live [high-speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_camera) video stream, the bandwidth limitations and electronic noise become important. Some YUV formats, like [uyvy](https://www.fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-uyvy/) or OMX_QCOM_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar32m, are optimized to reduce electron congestion on the way from optical sensor to byte buffer.

These formats may have significant advantage if used on the proper integrated circuit, or no advantage at all if used on a different type of hardware.

Same is true for hardware codecs. Different implementations of h264 decoder may take advantage of [cache locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) for different interlaced YUV formats.