# Does Android MediaCodec support RGBA encoding？

Tags: java, android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I have a set of Bitmap, need to be encoded into h264 video, Bitmap converted to RGBA byte [] sent to MediaCodec, but the exception: java.nio.BufferOverflowException

I would like to know if Android MediaCodec supports RBGA encoding?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Or another workaround to achieve encoding to H.264?

Thank you!

Comment: In the 1st comment of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463556/why-doesnt-the-decoder-of-mediacodec-output-a-unified-yuv-formatlike-yuv420p it is mentioned: "You can extract the RGB pixels from the output surface using glReadPixels()" maybe it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I can not use Surface, so it is not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load them into an openGL es texture and render to the encoder's input surface.
(maybe this will help: https://github.com/google/grafika)

Another option is to convert to the color format that the encoder support. (using libyuv for example)

Answer (score -1):

The MediaCodecInfo class as I [see](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html)  at Android developer page supports RGBA 32Bits, take a look at that class if it can helps :)

Comment: Thanks, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_Format32bitABGR8888 is this color format, but some phone hardware does not support this color format